# How to make edittext visible when a particular item is selected in spinner

Tags: android

I have a spinner with two values Manager and Member.
when I select Member the edittext become visible and if i select manager edittext become invisible.
Initially in the xml file I set visibility od the edittext as invisible.

here is my code:

```
gym = findViewById(R.id.lgymid);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Usertype, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        usertype.setAdapter(adapter);
        usertype.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if(text.equals("Manager"))
        {
            gym.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            gym.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        
    }
```

here gym is the edittext.
The above code is not working. It doesnt shows edittext if I select Member.

This is the xml code for edittext

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lgymid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Gym id"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Can you try logging `text` to be sure that you get "Manager" or "Member"?

Comment: Your `TextInputLayout` contains `EditText`. So If you make `TextInputLayout` invisible your `EditText` also be invisible. You must change  visibility 'TextInputLayout' from code instead changing visibility of `EditText`.